# Strikethrough in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos

When I enter a second date in a cell, I want the initial date to be strikethrough and keep the both date in the same cell

I have a range of cells from column E to H, in which each cell has date.

Your help would be highly appreciated

```
Sub ColorMeElmo()

'
Dim count As Long

count = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

'
 
   Dim i As Long, r1 As Range, r2 As Range

   For i = 2 To count
     
      Set r1 = Range("D" & i)
      
      
        Set r2 = Range("E" & i)
     
      Dim diff1 As Long
      diff1 = DateDiff("D", r2.Value, r1.Value)
      
      If diff1 <= 5 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
      If diff1 > 5 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbYellow
      
Next i

For ii = 2 To count
     
      Set r1 = Range("D" & ii)
      
      
        Set r2 = Range("F" & ii)
     
      Dim diff2 As Long
      diff2 = DateDiff("D", r2.Value, r1.Value)
      
      If diff2 <= 5 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
      If diff2 > 5 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbYellow
      
End Sub
```

Range will change from D, E, F, G, H. But here I give only E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your dates are already recognized as dates by Excel, you could use the following procedure:

```
Sub StrikethroughAndNewDate(ByRef rng As Range, ByVal NewDate As Date)

    'You can change this value if you need a different date format
    Const DateFormat As String = "YYYY-MM-DD"
    
    'Combine dates
    rng.Value2 = Format(rng.Value2, DateFormat) & " " & Format(NewDate, DateFormat)
    
    'Add Formatting
    rng.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=Len(Format(rng.Value2, DateFormat))).Font.Strikethrough = True

End Sub
```

Which would give you something like this :

[image]

If your dates are both stored as string inside the cells, you could do a simple concatenation instead:

```
Sub StrikethroughAndNewDate2(ByRef rng As Range, ByVal NewDate As Variant)
       
    'Combine dates
    rng.Value2 = rng.Value2 & " " & NewDate
    
    'Add Formatting
    rng.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=Len(rng.Value2)).Font.Strikethrough = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. When I run this I get "Argument Not Optional" compile error. I used 'Call StrikethroughAndNewDate' in the main procedure to call. How do I call, what parameter I should use to call. Thanks

Comment: @VinuVarghese You need to pass your arguments for the prodecure to work. You can do it like this: `StrikethroughAndNewDate r1, r2.value2`

Comment: Or switch r1 and r2 depending on what you want to do. It was not clear to me from your question.